# CImage destructor issue?

Tags: c++, mfc

I am using the function below to process an image in real time. The function is called every 10 seconds using a timer.

The problem is that I get an assertion failure , and can't figure out the exact problem. I tried CImage::ReleaseDC() and DeleteDC() for the ImageDC but no luck.

Any ideas ?

```
LRESULT CAutodetectDialog::AutoscanPatterns(WPARAM, LPARAM)
{
    HWND hwnd = ::FindWindow(NULL, windowTitle);

    if (hwnd != NULL)    
        for (int i=0; i<N_NUMBERS; i++)
        {        
            CImage image;
            image.Create(dbParams.width, dbParams.height, 24);

            CImageDC imageDC(image);
            ::SetWindowOrgEx(imageDC, db.topLeft.x, dbParams.topLeft.y + i * dbParams.height, NULL);
            ::PrintWindow(hwnd, imageDC, PW_CLIENTONLY);

            // Process the image - processing takes < 1 sec
            // and the image parameter is not being changed
            SaveImagePatterns(&image);                
        }            //   <-------------  This line fails , must be the destructor 
                     // of CImage : atlimage.h Line 884,  m_hDC == 0
                     // m_hDC is not NULL in the code

        return 0;
}


// Process the image - processing takes < 1 sec
// and the image parameter is not changed
void CAutodetectDialog::SaveImagePatterns(const CImage* image)
{
.........
}
```

This is the code that fails in atlimage.h :

```
inline HBITMAP CImage::Detach() throw()
{
    HBITMAP hBitmap;

    ATLASSUME( m_hBitmap != NULL );
    ATLASSUME( m_hDC == NULL );             // <------ This guy

    hBitmap = m_hBitmap;
...


...
return( hBitmap );
}
```

UPDATE : After commenting out the call to function SaveImagePatterns() , the assertion failure did not happen. So the problem must be in that function, despite the CImage param passed as **const**.

Comment: `The function is called every 10 seconds using a timer. `  And let's say the function for some reason takes more than 10 seconds.  What's stopping the function from being called while it's being executed?  Also, please state what `SaveImagePatterns` is supposed to do.  Note that your parameter is the address of a local variable, and local variables are destroyed automatically when that block exits.

Comment: Right, I should have mentioned that the execution time is less than 1 second and the timer was set to 10 seconds in order to avoid this kind of issues.

Comment: `SaveImagePatterns` seems the most likely culprit here. Show its code

Comment: @Wartin - That solution is a bandaid.  The real solution to the 10 seconds issue is to use proper synchronization, i.e. a critical section or mutex.

Comment: @Wartin - "........" doesn't tell us anything about how you're using that parameter or what that function does.  Please post the real code to the function, not dots.

Comment: Paul,  SaveImagePatterns() is calling other functions, and is quite large to include. As soon as the CImage parameter is not changed, does it really matter what it does ?

Comment: `As soon as the CImage parameter is not changed, does it really matter what it does `  "Not changed" doesn't mean "not saved somewhere.".  If indeed nothing is changed, why didn't you pass it as a (const) reference?   How about commenting out this call to SaveImagePattern()?  Does the problem still exist after commenting it out?

Comment: @Wartin - Also, since you declared the `CImageDCC` object after the `CImage` object, the order of destruction will be the `CImageDC` object, and then the `CImage` object.  If the order of destruction matters, then this also could be an issue if there is some sort of dependency on the two objects.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendations. It appears that the called function is causing the problem. I really can't imagine why , but I will take it from here. Paul you have provided an answer , and if you type one, I will accept as the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks suspicious:

```
SaveImagePatterns(&image);
```

Since `image` is a local variable, depending on what `SaveImagePatterns` does with it, this can cause an issue since the `image` object is destroyed as soon as that block is exited.

Answer (score 0):

Did you call any `image->GetDC()` by yourself in `SaveImagePatterns`?

Mind that `image->GetDC()` need to be paired with `image->ReleaseDC()`.

So that `m_hDC` will be `NULL`.